# TestNg load testing with parameters passed along with invocationCount and threadPoolSize

Tags: selenium-webdriver, load, testng, load-testing

As we know that in TestNG we can have a method running parallay being called by multiple threads,

```
@Test(invocationCount=5,threadPoolSize=5)
public void testMethod()
{
///code to generate load
}
```

Now we want to do the same thing but with 5 sets pf parameters for each thread invocation in parlall.

Comment: Is the `**` a part of the code or you want to bold the code? If you want to bold it, there's no need.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use data providers in TestNG for doing this.

Here's a sample that shows this

```java
//This method will provide data to any test method that declares that its Data Provider
//is named "test1"
@DataProvider(name = "test1")
public Object[][] createData1() {
 return new Object[][] {
   { "Cedric", new Integer(36) },
   { "Anne", new Integer(37)},
 };
}

//This test method declares that its data should be supplied by the Data Provider
//named "test1"
@Test(dataProvider = "test1")
public void verifyData1(String n1, Integer n2) {
 System.out.println(n1 + " " + n2);
}
```

Now in order to enable parallel execution, please make sure you add the attribute `data-provider-thread-count` and set its value to a desired value. The default value for this attribute is 10. This attribute lets you control your thread pool size for data providers in TestNG.

For e.g.,

```xml
<suite name="Unit-test-suite" verbose="2" data-provider-thread-count="15">
```

Take a look at the official documentation for it from [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders).

Comment: Thanks a Ton Krish..!..But what these two parameters @Test(invocationCount=5,threadPoolSize=5) have then?

Comment: They just tell TestNG to run the same test method n times and also tell TestNG the thread pool size. There is no parameterization in this case.